# Conflito na utilização de funções Javascript

Tags: javascript

Foi criada uma função clear() para limpar os números inseridos em um display por uma outra função addNumber(), porém a primeira função não está produzindo efeito algum ao ser usada.

Dicas de como posso resolver este problema, ou melhorar meu código?.

```js
const operation = document.querySelectorAll("[data-operation]")
const numbers = document.querySelectorAll("[data-content]")
const del = document.querySelector("[data-del]")
const allClear = document.querySelector("[data-ac]")
const displayPrevious = document.querySelector("[data-previous]")
const displayCurrent = document.querySelector("[data-current]")
const displayOperator = document.querySelector("[data-operator]")

function clear (){
    displayCurrent.innerHTML = " "
}
function addNumber(number){
    number = event.target.innerHTML
    if(number === "." && displayCurrent.innerHTML.includes(".")){
        return
    }
    displayCurrent.innerHTML += number
}
```

Comment: Tem o HTML para esse JS. Peço pois dependendo dos elementos evolvidos as vezes tem uma ou duas particularidades que podem ser exploradas facilitando a codificação.

Answer (score 0):

Diego, como você não postou todo o código, eu imaginei como poderia ser e me parece que está funcionando corretamente:

```js
const operation = document.querySelectorAll("[data-operation]");
const numbers = document.querySelectorAll("[data-content]");
const del = document.querySelector("[data-del]");
const allClear = document.querySelector("[data-ac]");
const displayPrevious = document.querySelector("[data-previous]");
const displayCurrent = document.querySelector("[data-current]");
const displayOperator = document.querySelector("[data-operator]");

function clear() {
    displayCurrent.innerHTML = " ";
}

function addNumber() {
    const number = event.target.innerHTML;
    if (number === "." && displayCurrent.innerHTML.includes(".")) {
        return;
    }

    displayCurrent.innerHTML += number;
}

numbers.forEach(a => a.addEventListener('click', addNumber));

allClear.addEventListener('click', clear);
```

```css
div[data-content] {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 6px;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
}

div[data-content]:hover {
  background: #efefef;
}
```

```html
<div data-content>1</div>
<div data-content>2</div>
<div data-content>3</div>
<div data-content>.</div>
<div>
    data-current: <span data-current></span>
</div>
<button data-ac>clear</button>
```

Se não for isso, por favor poste mais detalhes.

Comment: Realmente funcionou com esse seu código! o problema estava em o meu click estar sendo referido no HTML e não com um addEventListener no javascript?

Comment: @DiegoSousa que bom que funcionou! Eu não sei exatamente onde estava seu problema porque no código que você postou faltou os trechos do HTML e `addEventListener` mas talvez seja isso mesmo. abs

Answer (score -1):

Sua função tem um espaço inadequado

```
**function clear (){**
  displayCurrent.innerHTML = " "
}
```

deve ser:

```
function clear(){
   displayCurrent.innerHTML = " "
}
```

Comment: O espaço aparentemente não era o problema. a addNumber() funciona normalmente, mas há algo que não permite a função clear() alterar o HTML criado pela addNumber()